# PHP cUrl loop with echo

Tags: php, curl, echo, flush

I am trying to make a script which load urls from sitemap.xml and put it into array. They it should load all pages, one by one, and after each it should print something.

```
<?php 

set_time_limit(6000);

$urls = array();  

$DomDocument = new DOMDocument();
$DomDocument->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$DomDocument->load('sitemap.xml');
$DomNodeList = $DomDocument->getElementsByTagName('loc');


//parsovani xml, vkladani linku do pole
foreach($DomNodeList as $url) {
    $urls[] = $url->nodeValue;
}                   

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    $data = curl_exec($ch);    
    echo $url."<br />";
    flush();
    ob_flush();
}     

?>
```

Still doesn't work. Loading very long time, does not print anything. I think that flush does not work.

Does somebody see the problem??

Thank you very much
Filip

Comment: you don't need curl_init inside the loop. you can create ONE curl object and re-use it multiple times.

Comment: Can you show example to be sure, please? :)

Comment: You just need to echo out `$data`.  And you can probably save yourself a few lines of code by using `$data = file_get_contents($url);`

Comment: I would need to echo in each cycle. But maybe Gzip could take a part???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would run something like this

```
<?php 

set_time_limit(6000);

$urls = array();  

$DomDocument = new DOMDocument();
$DomDocument->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$DomDocument->load('sitemap.xml');
$DomNodeList = $DomDocument->getElementsByTagName('loc');


foreach($DomNodeList as $url) {
    $urls[] = $url->nodeValue;
}                   

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $url."<br />". $data;
}     

?>
```

Or even better instead of 2 loops.

```
<?php 

set_time_limit(6000);

$urls = array();  

$DomDocument = new DOMDocument();
$DomDocument->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$DomDocument->load('sitemap.xml');
$DomNodeList = $DomDocument->getElementsByTagName('loc');


foreach($DomNodeList as $url) {
    $curURL = $url->nodeValue;
    $urls[] = $curURL;
    $data = file_get_contents($curURL);
    echo $curURL."<br />". $data;
}     

?>
```

Comment: Thank you Garry. I appreciate it! It end up after few minutes by 500 ERROR :/.

Comment: You're probably getting an out of memory error. I would try running it from the command line, if that's an option for you... More efficient.. And change this line set_time_limit(6000), to this set_time_limit(0) -- That will tell your script not to timeout.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way how to print error in file? I have no option how to run it from console.

Comment: I would say to make sure error_reporting is on. You can do that directly from the script, just before the set_time_limit() call.

Comment: I just found it out. Problem is in buffer size and max execution time. They can't increase it. I will probably make C# application instead of php script. Thank you for everything